# how to show remaining data by comparing another table

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

```
Table 1: ABC                              table 2: PQR

code|Name|Amount                           code|Name|Amount
----+----+-----                            ----+----+------
1   | A  | 1000                             1  | A  | 1000
2   | B  | 2000                             2  | B  | 2000
3   | C  | 4000
4   | D  | 1000
```

data in table 2 is insert from data based on table 1, now by pressing a button named "Remaining" i want to show data that is not present in table 2, to know which tuples i have missed to fill from table 1. How can i do it?

Comment: What exactly is your question? Currently it´s far too broad. We don´t know what you´ve allready done and where you´re ctuck - two *essentially* neccessary information that you shopuld provide in your question.

Comment: `EXCEPT` - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/set-operators-except-and-intersect-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the fields in the 2 tables are exactly the same and in the same order?
But you can't bother to put those fields in the SQL?
Then you could also use an [EXCEPT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/set-operators-except-and-intersect-transact-sql)

```
SELECT * FROM ABC
EXCEPT
SELECT * FROM PQR;
```

And if you're not certain that the fields are in the same order?
Then list them in the SQL.
That has also the benefit that the SQL will probably still work when one of the tables is altered.

```
SELECT [code], [Name], [Amount] from ABC
EXCEPT
SELECT [code], [Name], [Amount] FROM PQR;
```

It filters out the PQR records that are exactly the same as those found in ABC.

But normally, the methods that Tim Biegeleisen showed are more commonly used.

Comment: Thanks Bro! i had forgot about the except in SQL. it worked for me

Comment: @GulshanSonwar Cool, thanks. But if you just need to know which codes are missing, then the NOT EXISTS linked on the code field would be better for that. An EXCEPT really compares the whole combination of the selected fields.

Answer (score 3):

This answer assumes that you want to find all records in the first table which are not already present in the second table.  One option uses a left join:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM ABC t1
LEFT JOIN PQR t2
    ON t1.code = t2.code AND t1.Name = t2.Name AND t1.Amount = t2.Amount
WHERE t2.code IS NULL;
```

We could also phrase this using `EXISTS`:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM ABC t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM PQR t2
                  WHERE t1.code = t2.code AND t1.Name = t2.Name AND
                        t1.Amount = t2.Amount);
```